# Android app crashes when changing intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm making an app but I have a problem:

In my MainActivity.java there are only 2 buttons, and when I click them, they should change Intent (every button has a different intent).

Android Studio doesn't give me any error and I can't solve it.

Here's the MainActivity.java

```
package com.valeriodesiati.graph2;
import android.content.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button b1, b2; //primo e secondo grado
Intent intent;
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Benvenuto!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    b1 = findViewById(R.id.button);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PrimoGrado.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    b2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondoGrado.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here's the first Intent:

```
package com.valeriodesiati.graph2;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.*;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PrimoGrado extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText a,b;
    private Button graficoButtonPrimoGrado;
    //float a1,b1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.primogrado);
    a = findViewById(R.id.a);
    b = findViewById(R.id.b);
    final float a1 = Float.parseFloat(a.getText().toString());
    final float b1 = Float.parseFloat(b.getText().toString());

    open2();

    graficoButtonPrimoGrado = findViewById(R.id.graficoButtonPrimoGrado);
    graficoButtonPrimoGrado.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(a1 == 0) {
                open(v);
                Intent iHome = new Intent(PrimoGrado.this, PrimoGrado.class);
                startActivity(iHome);
            }
            Intent i = new Intent(PrimoGrado.this, PrimoGradoGrafico.class);
            i.putExtra("a", String.valueOf(a));
            i.putExtra("b", String.valueOf(b));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

public void open(View view){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Se la a della retta è uguale a 0 è impossibile costruire il grafico.");
            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            Toast.makeText(PrimoGrado.this,"Riprova",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

public void open2 (){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Ricorda: inserisci i dati dell'equazione anche se sono uguali a 0");
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    Toast.makeText(PrimoGrado.this,"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
}
```

Here's the second Intent:

package com.valeriodesiati.graph2;

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.*;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SecondoGrado extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText a,b,c;
    private Button graficoButtonSecondoGrado;
    //float a1,b1,c1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.secondogrado);

        open2();

        a = findViewById(R.id.a);
        b = findViewById(R.id.b);
        c = findViewById(R.id.c);
        final float a1 = Float.parseFloat(a.getText().toString());
        final float b1 = Float.parseFloat(b.getText().toString());
        final float c1 = Float.parseFloat(c.getText().toString());

        graficoButtonSecondoGrado = findViewById(R.id.graficoButtonSecondoGrado);
        graficoButtonSecondoGrado.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(a1 == 0) {
                    open(v);
                }
                Intent i = new Intent(SecondoGrado.this, SecondoGradoGrafico.class);
                i.putExtra("a", String.valueOf(a));
                i.putExtra("b", String.valueOf(b));
                i.putExtra("c", String.valueOf(c));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }

    public void open(View view){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Se la a dell'equazione è uguale a 0 la parabola perderebbe il suo senso in quanto si ridurrebbe ad una retta");
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        Toast.makeText(SecondoGrado.this,"Riprova",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    public void open2 (){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Ricorda: inserisci i dati dell'equazione anche se sono uguali a 0");
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        Toast.makeText(SecondoGrado.this,"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Here's the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.valeriodesiati.graph2">

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity
                android:name="com.valeriodesiati.graph2.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.valeriodesiati.graph2.PrimoGrado"
                android:label="Primo grado"
                android:parentActivityName="com.valeriodesiati.graph2.MainActivity">

            </activity>

            <activity
                android:name="com.valeriodesiati.graph2.SecondoGrado"
                android:label="Primo grado"
                android:parentActivityName="com.valeriodesiati.graph2.MainActivity">

            </activity>

            <activity
                android:name="com.valeriodesiati.graph2.PrimoGradoGrafico"
                android:label="Primo grado"
                android:parentActivityName="com.valeriodesiati.graph2.PrimoGrado">

            </activity>

            <activity
                android:name="com.valeriodesiati.graph2.SecondoGradoGrafico"
                android:label="Primo grado"
                android:parentActivityName="com.valeriodesiati.graph2.SecondoGrado">

            </activity>

        </application>

    </manifest>
```

I know that I posted a lot of code, but I can't really get out of this problem.

Comment: post logcat error

Comment: can you share your crash report or logs

Comment: I think your app is crashing when you are clicking button 1, because there in PrimoGrado  Activity you are converting null to string. i.e                     final float a1 = Float.parseFloat(a.getText().toString());  Here a.getText is null untill you are taking some default vaule.

Comment: which button press crashes the app ??

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.valeriodesiati.graph2/com.valeriodesiati.graph2.PrimoGrado}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""

Comment: it crashes with both buttons.

Comment: can you explain me how convert it?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of this...

```
a = findViewById(R.id.a);
b = findViewById(R.id.b);
c = findViewById(R.id.c);
final float a1 = Float.parseFloat(a.getText().toString());
final float b1 = Float.parseFloat(b.getText().toString());
final float c1 = Float.parseFloat(c.getText().toString());
```

Since you JUST inialized a, b and c...you can not get a float value for `a1` since `a.getText().toString()` is null.

Comment: .... move the finals in the onClick methods.... if thats how you want to handle it. You want to get the float value of the EditText when you need it. You can't do that right of the bat.

Comment: you have to check if they are null then. i understand you may be new to development... but think about it before you just do what i say. if the edittext is empty, then you will get something thrown. either put it into a try catch, or wrap it around a simple if statement that checks if the value is null.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to avoid the `NullPointerException`:

```
float getFloatFromTextView(TextView textView) {
    if (textView != null) {
       try {
          return Float.parseFloat(textView.getText().toString());
       } catch(Throwable t) {
       }
    }
    return 0f;
} 

...
a = findViewById(R.id.a);
b = findViewById(R.id.b);
c = findViewById(R.id.c);
final float a1 = getFloatFromTextView(a);
final float b1 = getFloatFromTextView(b); 
final float c1 = getFloatFromTextView(c);
```